# SSRS datetime parameter includes "+01:00"

Tags: datetime, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with a DateTime parameter.

The issue only arises when the user enters the day and month i.e. 1/8. After enter, the parameter field on thescreen contains:

**01/08/2016 00:00:00 +01:00**

In my report I am displaying this parameter value and when the user enters the datetime as above all I see is "#Error".

I have tried various combinations of CStr, Format, FormatDateTime etc with no success.

If I display just the parameter value without any formatting I see the following:

**8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM +01:00**

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was the Textbox formatting was set to Default.

I changed this to be Custom: **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**, which displayed as expected.